# Pytorch "hipErrorNoBinaryForGpu: Unable to find code object for all current devices!"

Tags: pytorch, amd-rocm

SYSTEM: Ryzen 5800x, rx 6700xt, 32 gigs of RAM, Ubuntu 22.04.1

I'm attempting to install Stable-Diffusion by following https://youtu.be/d_CgaHyA_n4

When attempting to run the SD script, I get the `"hipErrorNoBinaryForGpu: Unable to find code object for all current devices!"` error.

I believe this is caused by PyTorch not working as expected. When validating Pytorchs' installation with "[The Master Test](https://wandb.ai/wandb/common-ml-errors/reports/How-To-Use-GPU-with-PyTorch---VmlldzozMzAxMDk)", I get the same error:

```
"hipErrorNoBinaryForGpu: Unable to find code object for all current devices!"
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I believe that it is install correctly as using the `conda list` command tells me that torch 1.12.0a0+git2a932eb and torchvision 0.13.0a0+f5afae5 are installed. Interestingly, when I change the command ever-so-slightly to torch.cuda.is_available, (without the parentheses), I get the following output: `<function is_available at 0x7f42278788b0>`. Granted, I'm not sure what this is telling me. Following the "[Verification](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#linux-verification)" step resulted in the expected array of random numbers. However, failed the GPU driver check.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Try running the following command:

`export HSA_OVERRIDE_GFX_VERSION=10.3.0`

This made it work on my machine using an RX 6600 XT, with which I got the same error running it, before exporting the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with ROCm enabled Tensorflow, the tensorflow-rocm, package. Without setting up the environment variable
`export HSA_OVERRIDE_GFX_VERSION=10.3.0`
, tensorflow-rocm crashes.

After setting it up, it works with 6700XT as well (at least it does not crash.) But still having problem with finding libraries.

It seems ROCm has a lot to catch up.